# Android - get content of certain array-field to a String

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I am trying to get the content of a single array item.

In my code, I want the value of `String suitId` to have the content of `suitIdArray[getSuitId];`, but it doesn't get the content.

Could you please help me to see what is wrong. Here is my code...

```
Object item1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem();
int getDragId = spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();
String suitId;

if(!item1.equals("Choose size")) {
    suitId = suitIdArray[getSuitId];
}
else {
    pSuit = null;
}
```

Comment: If your question has been answered, or if it is no longer valid, please 'tick' to choose the most appropriate answer so everyone knows that the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is is not working because you have a variable `getdragid` but you're using `getsuitid` in the array? ie, should it be the following...

```
Object item1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem();
int getdragtid = spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();
if(!item1.equals("Choose size"))
{
    suitid = suitidarray[getdragtid]; // I changed this line
}
else if(item1.equals("Choose size"))
{
    psuit = null;
}
```

Otherwise, I'm not really sure what you're trying to do?